# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema de erro que se me rompe la pagina al convertirse en Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy enfrentando un problema con la **apariencia del ícono del menú en mi pagina web**.

Una vez que el menú está abierto, **no logro hacer que desaparezca correctamente dentro del menú**, en su lugar aparece junto al ícono de cierre del menú.

Además, el botón o ícono de búsqueda está descentralizado y no sé cómo alinearlo correctamente junto al ícono del menú. **Mi objetivo es que el ícono del menú esté en el margen lateral de la página, el ícono de búsqueda a su izquierda y, por supuesto, el título en el otro lado del margen de la página**.

```js
// FUNCIÓN DE ENCABEZADO
const nav = document.querySelector("#nav");
const abrir = document.querySelector("#abrir");
const close = document.querySelector("#cerrar");

abrir.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.add("visible");
});

close.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.remove("visible");
})
```

```css
/* ESTILOS GENERALES */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

/* ESTILOS DE LA CABECERA */

.head {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  background: #A52A2A;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.head .logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.head .logo h1 {
  font-size: 29px;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.head .logo h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #dedede;
}

.head .navbar {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.head .navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.head .navbar a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

/* ESTILO DEL BOTÓN HAMBURGUESA */

.abrir-menu,
.cerrar-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .abrir-menu {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .cerrar-menu {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .nav {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 1rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax #00000080;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .cerrar-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .nav.visible .abrir-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav.visible .cerrar-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }

  .navbar a {
    color: #ffffffec;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .navbar a:hover {
    color: #5a5a5a8c;
  }
}

/* ESTILOS DE LA BARRA DEL BUSCADOR */

.head .search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }

.head .search-bar input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 24px;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.head .search-bar input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-color: #ffffff00;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.head .btn-bar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #742020;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.head .btn-bar i {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.head .search-bar:hover input {
  width: 300px;
}

.head .search-bar:hover i {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .head {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .head .navbar {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .head .search-bar {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .head .btn-bar {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>World Music</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/logo.jpg" type="image/x-icon" id="x-icon">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb496ab1a0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <!-- CUERPO -->
    <body>
        <div class="head">     
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>World Music</h1>
                <h2>Reciclaje de autopartes</h2>
            </div>  
                    <button id="abrir" class="abrir-menu"><i class="bi bi-list"></i></button>
                <nav class="nav" id="nav">
                    <button class="cerrar-menu" id="cerrar"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></button>
                        <nav class="navbar">
                            <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                            <a href="#">Categoria</a>
                            <a href="ofertas.html">Ofertas</a>
                            <a href="historial.html">Historial</a>
                            <a href="ayuda.html">Ayuda</a>
                            <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
                        </nav>
                </nav>
            <div class="search-bar">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
                <div class="btn-bar"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Así se ve mejor mi problema]